# Test: How can I tap on a Google Map marker inside my app using maestro mobile UI testing framework

Tags: testing, mobile, nativescript, maestro

I'm new to programming and Maestro. I'm developing a native application using Vue3 and Nativescript that uses the Google Maps plugin. I've added multiple markers on the map and need to perform some tests, specifically tapping on a marker.
I have installed Maestro with Maestro Studio. I've tried to write some tests in .yaml, but it doesn't work. I cannot tap on the marker on the map. Here is the code from my app where I add a marker:

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref, $navigateBack } from 'nativescript-vue';
import { GoogleMap, MapType, MapReadyEvent, MapView, MarkerOptions, Marker, MapTapEvent } from '@nativescript/google-maps';

const mapView = ref<GoogleMap | null>(null);
function onReady(event: MapReadyEvent) {
  mapView.value = event.map;

  const markerOptions: MarkerOptions = {
    position: {
        lat:51.33,
        lng:12.37
    },
    title: "New_Marker",

};
  const newMarker: Marker = event.map.addMarker(markerOptions);
  console.log("MARKEER INFO: " + newMarker);

}
function onTap(event: MapTapEvent) {
  console.log("Map tapped!", event);

}
function addMarker(map: GoogleMap, markerOptions: MarkerOptions): Marker {
  return map.addMarker(markerOptions);
}

function mapLongPress(event: MapTapEvent){



}

</script>

<template>
<Page actionBarHidden="true">
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
<Label
      testID="goBack"
        text="Go Back"
        @tap="$navigateBack"
        class="text-center px-4 py-10 text-2xl text-gray-900 font-bold"
      />


<ContentView row="1" class="bg-[#65adf1] rounded-t-3xl">
<MapView
        testID="gMaps"
        @onTap ="onTap"        
        @ready="onReady"
        @mapLongPress="mapLongPress"


/>
</ContentView>
</GridLayout>
</Page>
</template>
```

and here is my firstTest.yaml:

```yaml
appId: org.nativescript.myAwesomeApp


- launchApp:
      clearState: true


- tapOn:
      id: "gMap"
- tapOn:
        containsDescendants:
        text: "New_Marker"`
```

here is output in terminal:

Waiting for flows to complete...

[Failed] markerTest (41s) (Element not found: Text matching regex: New_Marker)

1/1 Flow Failed

Comment: I'm noticing a couple small inconsistencies in your code (`containsDescendants:` should have less indentation than the `text:` under it, you're looking for `id` `gMap`, but I only see `gMaps` in your code), so you could try correcting those, but the best thing to do would be to launch Maestro Studio with your app running and see if you can find the selector `"New_Marker"` with Maestro Studio. Maestro Studio is generally the best way to find selectors and start writing tests.

Maestro also has a helpful [Slack channel](https://docsend.com/view/3r2sf8fvvcjxvbtk) you could post in.